# How I can save data in two tables simultaneously in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have the following data mode
[image]l

`Detalle_Servicio` has many `Material_Usado` and `Material_Usado` belongs only `Detalle_Servicio`

When I save values ​​in Material_Usado should know the ID Detelle_Servido, but as I can not do that. I have the following code

**Route**

```
Route::post('/upload', function(){

    $path = public_path().'/servicios';
    try{
        $upload_success1 = Input::file('foto1')->move($path,'1');
        $upload_success2 = Input::file('foto2')->move($path,'2');
        $upload_success3 = Input::file('foto3')->move($path,'3');
        $upload_success4 = Input::file('foto4')->move($path,'4');
    }catch(Exception $e) {
        $e->getMessage();
    }
    $input = Input::get('json');
    $json = json_decode($input);

    if($upload_success1 && $upload_success2 && $upload_success3 && $upload_success4) {
        //DB::insert("INSERT INTO Detalle_Servicio (RutaFoto1, RutaFoto2, RutaFoto3, RutaFoto4, FechaTermino, Latitud, Longitud, Servicio_idServicio) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", array($path.'1', $path.'2', $path.'3', $path.'4',$json->termino, $json->latitud, $json->longitud, $json->idServicio));
        $entradas = array(
                    'RutaFoto1' => $path.'1',
                    'RutaFoto2' => $path.'2',
                    'RutaFoto3' => $path.'3',
                    'RutaFoto4' => $path.'4',
                    'FechaTermino' => $json->termino,
                    'Latitud' => $json->latitud,
                    'Longitud' => $json->longitud,
                    'Servicio_idServicio' => $json->idServicio
                    );
        Detalle_Servicio::create($entradas);

       $array = array('Code' => '202', 'Message' => 'Done');
       return Response::json($array);
    } else {
        $array = array('Code');
       return Response::json('error', 400);
    }


 });
```

*You can see that I get a JSON containing the values ​​that I store in the database*

I keep the data in the database of the `Detalle_Servicio` table but then I need to save some data in `Material _Usado` but I need the ID that was generated when you save the data in the table `Detalle_Servicio`

**Model**

```
class Detalle_Servicio extends Eloquent{
protected $table = 'Detalle_Servicio';
protected $primaryKey = 'idDetalle_Servicio';
protected $fillable = array('RutaFoto1', 'RutaFoto2', 'RutaFoto3', 'RutaFoto4', 'FechaTermino', 'Latitud', 'Longitud', 'Servicio_idServicio');


public function servicio(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Servicio', 'idServicio'); //le pertenece a
}
public function material_usado(){
    return $this->hasMany('Material_Usado', 'idMaterial_Usado');
}
}
```

and

```
class Material_Usado extends Eloquent{
protected $table = 'Material_Usado';
protected $primaryKey = 'idMaterial_Usado';

public function detalleServicio(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Detalle_Servicio', 'idDetalle_Servicio');
}
}
```

how can I do it?

Comment: My initial inclination would be to use a procedure and a package, wrapping it in transaction logic and update each table if either update fails rollback transaction, if both successful commit.  This would be accomplished using parameters procedures like http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=3750

Comment: But why you can't use the id of just saved model? Where do you save the other one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use this:

```
Detalle_Servicio::create($entradas);
```

It returns the model instance that was just created so you should do it like this way:

```
$Detalle_Servicio = Detalle_Servicio::create($entradas);
```

Now you can get the id of the created model using:

```
$Detalle_Servicio->id;
```

So, you may do something like this:

```
if($Detalle_Servicio = Detalle_Servicio::create($entradas)) {
    $id = $Detalle_Servicio->id;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand why you have this function in routes.php. Unless this is for example only...then you should have this a controller which will save the models in order.

First save the first model and then simply retrieve the foreign key that you need using something like this:

```
$serviceDetail = new Detalle_Servicio;
$serviceDetail->rutaFoto1 = Input::get('upload_success1');
etc..
$serviceDetail->save();

if ($serviceDetail->id)
{
$serviceDetail->material_usado()->attach($serviceDetail->id);
}
```

hope I understood the question :)